# Facebook Login and Logout only for my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to use Facebook PHP SDK to Login and Logout users only for my site.
Currently with the tutorials and examples provided, if i Logout from the website automatically will Logout even from Facebook.com.

Comment: What is the point of logging out of your site if they're still logged into Facebook?

Comment: To bypass the registration step in the site

Comment: Could you set a cookie with your sites login that gets set when they log in with facebook, and then when they click "log out" you just revoke the cookie and don't even touch FB's logout function?

Comment: @Esaevian This may work for me, do you have any example in order to give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

Use facebook api only for login and implement your own controller for logout to clear login session of user with your website.